# Cakephp Image from external url

Tags: css, image, cakephp, include

I have several image links in my db.
Those links are absolute urls.

My problem is, that Cake won't show the image.

My view:

```
<h2><?php echo h($item['Item']['title']); ?></h2>
<img src="<?php echo h($item['Item']['cover']); ?>">
```

Displays:

```
"My title" (in h2)
and no image
```

Firebug output is the following, the "img" tag is shown in grey:

```
<h2>My title</h2>
<img src="http://example.com/images/SY317.jpg">
```

For testing, I have deleted all css files from webroot/css.

**Does anybody know where my error is?**
I can't figure it out.

Comment: the image doesn't exist or the path is wrong.

Comment: yes indeed, i just noticed a 403 forbidden error in firebugs networking tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listed code:

```
<img src="<?php echo h($item['Item']['cover']); ?>">
```

Translates to "normal" PHP:

```
<img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($item['Item']['cover']); ?>">
```

The URL formatting looks fine, so the image just likely does not exist.  This really has nothing to do with CakePHP (or even PHP for that matter).

Even though it's an external image, it's still a good idea to use CakePHP's Html helper to display the image.  This allows you to manipulate images across the site easier... like if you wanted to add a watermark, or track # of image views, or use a thumbnailer...etc etc:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image($item['Item']['cover'], array(
    'height'=>'100',
    'width'=>'100',
    'alt'=>'my image')); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the cake HtmlHelper functions like this:

```
<?php echo $html->image($item['Item']['cover']); ?>
```

Comment: 1) syntax is from CakePHP 1.2 (OLD), and 2) he asked about an image, not a link